# React Native project cannot open real device (Can Not connect metro server 8081)

Tags: ios, macos, react-native

Hi I create proje yesterday always very nice but now  simulator connected metro bundler but  real device cannot connect and can not show home page just I see splash screen and not any error just white screen what can I do  . React native  always problem:(

Answer (score 1):

In your real device, you should connect to PC with cable, and connect to wifi or Lan- which same PC of you. sorry because my EL.

Answer (score 0):

Now if you want to see the error either you can run

```
$ react-native log-ios
$ react-native log-android

Or
```

You can you can check the error in android studio and xCode
and if you are running in debug mode the stop debugging

Answer (score 0):

I connect my phone's internet. after restart modem and forget wifi. after I connect my modem and this is solutions.